# Renaming an element with name Standard into Product using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I had to transform following xml input,

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
            <DraftProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </DraftProducts>
            <ReferenceProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320056</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934789</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </ReferenceProducts>
            <RelatedIntProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116881</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208076</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116886</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedIntProducts>
            <S1>1001</S1>
            <S2>1986</S2>
        </Standard>
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200058</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1002</SNumber>
            <DraftProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500167</ProductID>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </DraftProducts>
            <ReferenceProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263974</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320052</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934754</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </ReferenceProducts>
            <RelatedIntProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116837</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208074</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116843</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedIntProducts>
            <S1>1005</S1>
            <S2>1983</S2>
        </Standard>
    </Standards>
```

into the following output format.

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
            <RelatedProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                    <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320056</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934789</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116881</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208076</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116886</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedProducts>
            <S1>1001</S1>
            <S2>1986</S2>
        </Standard>
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200058</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1002</SNumber>
            <RelatedProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500167</ProductID>
                    <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263974</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320052</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934754</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116837</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208074</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116843</RelationId>
                    <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedProducts>
            <S1>1005</S1>
            <S2>1983</S2>
        </Standard>
    </Standards>
```

With the support from the others in the forum I was able to write the following xslt to do this transformation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
    xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
    exclude-result-prefixes="x"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:Standard">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductID"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Prefix"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:SNumber"/>
            <RelatedProducts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//x:RelatedProduct"/>
            </RelatedProducts>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S1"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S2"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:RelatedProduct">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <RelationType><xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/></RelationType>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But now I need to rename all the elements currently named as Standard into Product and the final output should be as follows.

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Product>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <RelatedProducts>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>320056</ProductID>
                <RelationId>934789</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <RelationId>116881</RelationId>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>208076</ProductID>
                <RelationId>116886</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
        </RelatedProducts>
        <S1>1001</S1>
        <S2>1986</S2>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductID>200058</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1002</SNumber>
        <RelatedProducts>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>1500167</ProductID>
                <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>263974</ProductID>
                <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>320052</ProductID>
                <RelationId>934754</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <RelationId>116837</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>208074</ProductID>
                <RelationId>116843</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
        </RelatedProducts>
        <S1>1005</S1>
        <S2>1983</S2>
    </Product>
</Standards>
```

I tried several approaches and changed the above xslt, but still there's no luck. I am a novice to xslt. How can I change the above xslt to get this thing done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `<xsl:copy>` in

```
<xsl:template match="x:Standard">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductID" />
```

with `<Product>` (and the closing tag, too, of course). It's that easy without modifying something else, giving

```
<xsl:template match="x:Standard">
                <Product>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductID" />
```

Result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Product>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <RelatedProducts>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            ...
```

If you want to also copy the `RelationId` just remove the exeception from the last template, so that it looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="x:RelatedProduct">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    <RelationType><xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/></RelationType>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Applying both gives you the exact result.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not give me the expected result.

Comment: I compared both results and except for `RelationID` they were identical. However, I updated my answer relating to this.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, your solution seems to work. Here's my vote. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. I have approved it back again !

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.